# $\sup${$\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}:n\in\mathbb Z$}: Upper boundary of $\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, supremum-and-infimum, sequence-of-function

> EDITED: By Lord Shark the Unknown's answer, seems like the boundary should be $1\over{\vert\sin x\vert}$, but can anyone give a supplement to the proof?

Observing the functions $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ (Of course for some $a\in $ dom$(f_n)$, it evaluate as $0\over 0$, then they are define as limit of $f(x)$ for $x$ around $a$)

See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utuxzadryg) for a Desmos graph.

I observe that when $n\to\infty$ , $f_n$ seems to be a 'space filling curve'.

[image]

**I would like to ask, what is the upper boundary (which is not defined for  {$k\pi:k\in\mathbb Z$}), in terms of function?**

Should it be $U(x)=\sup${$f_n(x):n\in\mathbb Z$}? I'm not pretty sure about it. (Is it about the irrationality of $\pi$?)

Also I think that it is enough to consider the cases of $f_n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ since $\forall x\in\mathbb R, \sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is not a rational
multiple of $\pi$, then $\sin nx$ will approach $1$ and $-1$ arbitrarily closely as $n$ varies. Therefore
$$\sup_n \frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}=\frac1{|\sin x|}$$
as long as $x$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Can you give a proof to your first sentence? Also, what if $x=\frac{p}{q}\pi$,while $p\in\mathbb Z,q\in\mathbb N,\frac{p}{q}\notin\mathbb Z$? I observe that if $x={\pi\over 2}$, when $n=2k+1$ ,$\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x} = {1 \over{\vert\sin x\vert}}$. But seems if $x={\pi\over3}$, the supremum isn't? Can you give a general result to the case when $x$ is a rational multiple but not a multiple of $\pi$?